# RxJava subscribe event is called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, rx-java, android-lifecycle

I am developing an Android app.
1M users are using the app.

The app is using RxJava as a global event bus.

I have a fragment.

```kotlin
class MyFragment {

    private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        disposable.add(
            RxEventBus.getInstance()
                    .toObservable()
                    .subscribe { event: Event ->
                        go()
                    }
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        disposable.dispose()
    }

    private fun go() {
       Log.d(TAG, "go!!!");
    }
}
```

But I got some user reports that the "go()" function is called twice!!!

I don't know why...

Somebody help me please?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4440

Comment: Can you post the code snippet from where the event is sent?